# usercontrol find button control in parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, parent-child

I have a usercontrol that is inside another user control, what I would like to do is after a certain process runs to find the button control in the parent and run the OnClick event.

usercontrol 1

```
protected void btnReload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //reloads data
}
```

usercontrol 2 (embeded in usercontrol 1)

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnReload = (Button)Parent.FindControl("btnReload");
    //here fire the btnReload onclick even
}
```

if this is not the best way I take recomendations cause I'm to the point of pulling my hair out over this.  The reason I am doing this is because I have 8 pages that all require to create a new user so I would like to use 1 usercontrol for that but reload the page they are on with that new user created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it :

**1. On Server Side.**

What you are trying to do is architecture wise wrong, child should not try to find controls in parents and neither should parent. So Child control can have a custom event, parent can register to it and you can fire that event on child control's button click event.

Here's an article to get you started : http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2004/10/06/easily-raise-events-from-asp-net-ascx-user-controls/

This has also been discussed here : [How do you determine when a button is clicked in the child on the parent - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448363/how-do-you-determine-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-the-child-on-the-parent-asp-n)

**2. Client Side :**

Using JQuery, you can catch child control's button click event and from there you can fire parent's button's click. You can share parent's button's id using a hidden variable.

Comment: Ok this is working just as I need it to but is there a way to pass a string value from the usercontrol back to the aspx through event arguments?

Comment: Yes. If you look in the codebetter example, they have a class TabClickEventArgs inherited from EventArgs class. Just follow that class, whatever value you want to pass, create a property for it, set it before firing the event and parent should get it.

Comment: Found it but im getting an error at this line: MyControl.TabClicked += new EventHandler(btnNewUser_Click);

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that.
A UserControl should be a self-contained chunk that doesn't need to know about its surroundings.

Instead, create an event in your UserControl and handle it in the parent page.  You can move the click handler to a separate method and call that method from both the button click event and your new custom event.